# Node Express Request BodyParser object rounds long numbers

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, long-integer

in some of my previous posts, I was stating that mongoose long data type is inserting a long number data type into MongoDB but it rounds the last 3 positions of a big 18 positions long number... 
But today however, I found out thats not the case, I created a long number manually in the app.js and saved it, and in the database it was correctly inserted without rounding, here is the code:

```
var Part = db.model('Part', partSchema);
var part = new Part({ _id: "1234567891234567815" });
part.save()
```

so it must be on the requests bodyParser side, where I send the number via an API to the server, where its entered into MongoDB afterwards...

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

so the problem is that somehow requests does not accept very long numbers, and somehow rounds them at some point or precision.. is there a way to accept long numbers with at least 18 positions? Or can you somehow parse them in a "raw" way?

Comment: Send it as a string instead of a number.

Comment: well originally, I wanted to send them as string, from python, but then the json document format is not recognized as valid in the request body...I had to use ast.literal_eval(document) to strip off all " " and ' '